# ViEmu isn't in my Tools | Options, and not in my Un-install list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vim, resharper, viemu

I have vs.net 2010, and `resharper`.

I installed the trial of `viEmu`, but I don't have the Tools | Options -> Viemu option menu and can't change some keyboard bindings.

The top level viEmu menu that I have circled in red doesn't have the keyboard mapping popup box etc., that is in the Tools | Options then viEmu menu item.

[image]

**Worse yet**, I don't have the option to un-install viemu as its not in my uninstall list.

Any ideas what I can do on both of these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ViEmu install as an **extension** in your VS2010, so you should be able to uninstall it  in `Menu|Tools -> Extension Manager -> Installed Extensions -> ViEmu`.

[image: uninstall ViEmu in VS2010]

Second, you can toggle ViEmu on and off at `Menu|ViEmu -> Enable/Disable ViEmu` without uninstall it.

And about the ViEmu's keybinding settings, you can enable all ViEmu default binding by pressing `Menu|ViEmu -> Set Keybindings`. And adjust or reset them in `Tools-> Options -> Environment->Keyboard` like @eric-laforce said.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in Tools->Options under Environment->Keyboard?

[image]

Comment: Yes I see that, but how do I remove it and get it back if I want it later?

Comment: There is an enable/disable feature that you can add a keyboard shortcut for.  In my screenshot see the ViEmu.EnableDisableViEmu